# How to Move the Controls in from a Grid to a child TabControl using VisualStateManager in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend, visualstatemanager

Basically we need to update the layout at runtime depending on some logic. For achieving it we are using visualstatemanager. Now in a scenario we have to move our controls from the grid to a tabcontrol (which is also part of the same grid). Any idea that how can we achieve this?

Would prefer to get it done using xaml (VisualStateManager) instead of writing the code to remove the control from grid and add it into tabcontrol.

Comment: Actually moving it in code during runtime probably isn't something you really want to even try to do. Instead you might consider having your controls in a UserControl or a template of sorts and place it in both spots and just toggle the visibility accordingly instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Doing that would require to create multiple instances of the control. right? if yes then that is again a problem for me as i dont want to create multiple instances of the control.